# How to reopen user's session and force him to authenticate if his password was changed or expired in Sping security?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have a simple Spring security config for "Basic auth" in my app. Now I need to implement password expiration. My question is how can I close a user's active session if his password was changed? First I thought about `server.servlet.session.timeout` but then I have discovered that this timeout starts from the last user's request. But in my application it is normal, if I receive requests every 5 seconds from a particular user, this means that the user may remain logged in for a very long time despite his password was changed by user (for avoiding password expiration) or expired.

Here is my security config:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final AuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.customAuthenticationProvider = customAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/app/user",
                        "/app/user/password/refresh"
                ).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

}



@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);
    private final UserService userService;

    public CustomAuthenticationProvider(@NonNull final UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        String userName = authentication.getName();
        User user = userService.getUserByName(userName);
        String encryptedPassword = DigestUtils.encodePassword(authentication.getCredentials().toString(), user.getSalt());
        String encryptedPasswordFromDb = user.getPassword();

        //TODO add validating expiration date
        if (encryptedPassword.equals(encryptedPasswordFromDb)) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userName,
                    encryptedPassword,
                    List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(String.format(
                            "ROLE_%s",
                            user.getRoleName()
                    ))));
        }

        log.error("Incorrect password for user {}", userName);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Incorrect password for user %s", userName));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question confused me somewhat - `the user may remain logged in for a very long time despite his password was changed` - this seems to imply that someone other than the user himself can change his password, correct? If my understanding is correct, then this is a security issue - first someone else will be aware of the user's password, and second this someone will have to send the password somehow to the user (email for example). The standard flow is that the user remains logged in, if his password expires during active session, and the next time he logs in you force him to change it.

Comment: What do you mean with a password expiring? How can a password expire?

Comment: No, I mean that user changes his password by himself via api that I should implement. But as he stays in an active session, I suppose a method “ authenticate” will not be called until this session expires even if password was changed. I’m trying to figure out is there any way to force closing session right after password was changed by user in order to call method “authenticate” with new password that he will pass

Comment: @Toerktumlare I will add column “expiration_date” in table with users and I will check if expiration_date + 1 year > current_date while authenticate user

Comment: Just invalidate the session then

Comment: How can I do it properly? At what point of my app? I would be grateful if you share some examples

Comment: @Toerktumlare And also how can invalidate session right after password expires?

Comment: Why? Password expiry doesn’t have to be enforced to the minute and second. The user had a valid password when he logged in, and he won’t next time. This requirement cannot be serious.

Comment: Let's say you enforce password renewal the moment the old one expires (user definitely won't be happy that you disrupt him for no good reason, but ...). Why do you want to do that? From security pov, you already know that the user is changing his own password (he is logged), from user experience pov you are giving him bad experience for no benefit. If you are calling the shots, I am urging you to rethink your choice (you will be reworking it). If that's a client request, do your best to convince him this is a bad idea (he will have you reworking it) and choose some stardard (sane) workflow.